# Redirect to login page unless a user is logged in

Tags: php, mysql, session, redirect

I'm trying to set up a page that is only accessible if a user is logged in and otherwise redirects to the login page.

I have the below function which I got from the book 'PHP and mySQL in In Easy Steps' but when no user is logged in it just hangs and does not redirect. I've checked for transcription errors and don't see any problem.

I've also tried using `header()` directly and I've also tried using `ob_start()` in case it was a problem with the header not being sent first - but still I can't get it to work and can't see what the problem is. Any guidance would be much appreciated!

```
<?php
    SESSION_START();

    function load($page='login.php') {
        $url='http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
        $url=rtrim($url,'/\\');
        $url.='/'.$page;
        header("Location:$url");
        exit();
    }

    if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
        load('login.php');
    }

    include_once('includes/header.html');
    /* ...rest of webpage...*/
    include_once('includes/footer.html');
?>
```

Comment: `$_SESSION('userid')` needs to be `$_SESSION['userid']` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have syntax error here in the below line:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION('userid'))) {
```

change to

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
```

$_SESSION is an array not a function!

Comment: Thanks @ashique-c-m @Ram-Sharma and @TiiJ7. Very sorry, I've updated my original question code to use  `$_SESSION['userid']` ...however this was a typo in stackoverflow only - the redirection still does not work unfortunately. Can you see any other problem I'm missing?

Comment: defenitly this should work, just print the session and debug. print_r($_SESSION);

Comment: Thank you :) I checked my actual program and found that it works if I define the function directly in the code (as in the code in my question) rather than using `require_once('includes/functions.php');`. I suppose a `require()` interrupts the `header()`...